# iOS storyboard, autolayout: IB munges width of UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uidatepicker, autolayout

I'm building a storyboard for iPhone 5, iOS 6, using Xcode 4.6.1.

One of my scenes, for a UIViewController subclass, includes a UIDatePicker in the root view.

The height of UIDatePicker is fixed, and IB assigns a height constraint to match. Surprisingly, IB allows the picker any width you want. I've set the following horizontal constraints on the picker:

- Leading space from superview = 0
- Width = 320
- Trailing space unspecified

That should be enough to be both consistent and complete.

Whenever I close the storyboard (Xcode seems to do so whenever I perform a version-control operation), and open it again, IB sets the width to 480 (160 points beyond the trailing edge of the superview). The constraints are still in place.

Changing the constraints to zero leading and trailing distance from the superview, and leaving the width free:

- Leading space from superview = 0
- Width unspecified
- Trailing space from superview = 0

changed the size of the picker as expected when I made the change, but has no effect on the bug. When the storyboard is reopened, the width is set to 480, and the constraints I set (zero points leading and trailing) are still in place.

I've set my constraints to priority 1000, but I'm just thrashing.

Does anyone know how to get IB to do what I want? Will it all turn out okay when the app runs?

Comment: That's very odd. I'm not able to duplicate the issue. When you run in the simulator do you see any issues? Also are you logging the constraint issues to see if there are any ambiguous layouts elsewhere?

Comment: I get much better results creating and applying constraints from code.

Comment: I am seeing a very similar thing, when I switch to Landscape my height constraint disappears causing the UIDatePicker to overlap other elements on the storybook.

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same problem, which does not help when you are trying to port to iOS 7.